# Filter not Exists yielding confusing results

Tags: sparql

I tried the following query in sparql:

```
Select distinct (count(?jel) AS ?jelCount )

Where {

  ?jel a skos:Concept .
  ?jel skos:prefLabel ?label .


  Filter not Exists {
    ?jel skos:narrower ?narrower .
    ?jel skos:notation ?notation .
  }             
}
```

However it does not give me the answer i want, it actually filter nothing.

However if i write:

```
Select distinct (count(?jel) AS ?jelCount )

Where {

  ?jel a skos:Concept .
  ?jel skos:prefLabel ?label .


Filter not Exists {
    ?jel skos:narrower ?narrower .
  }

  Filter not Exists {
    ?jel skos:notation ?notation .
  }

}
```

Then i get the answer that i want.

I am not able to explain why ? Can someone enlighten me on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SPARQL the entirety of each pattern (denoted by `{ }`) must match to have an effect.

So your first query asks for items where **both** of the `skos:narrower` and `skos:notation` triples do not exist for an item because they are in the same `FILTER NOT EXISTS` pattern.  Presumably there are no items where both of those triples exist for an item in your data and thus nothing is filtered out.

However in your second query you ask for items where **either** of the `skos:narrower` or `skos:notation` do not exist (because each is in a separate `FILTER NOT EXISTS` pattern).  As there are some of these triples for some items in your data then some things are filtered out.

Comment: Subtle but "logical", totally "logical" :) ! Thanks